# Laravel Maintenance Mode return 200 status code

Tags: laravel

I have created a page in under maintenance mode with some functionalities where the user can register. Although when trying to run some campaigns with the link Facebook says that the page is not functional, probably because it returns a 503 status code.
Is there a way to return a status code 200 instead of a 503 in under maintenance mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
php artisan down --status=200
```